# Obter apenas numeros em um input que recebe XX ml (exemplo: 200ml)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando a mascara do Jquery para colocar automaticamente o sufixo ml (mililitro) no input que recebe o tamanho de uma garrafa.

sendo o id do input #tamanho:

`var tamanho = $("#tamanho").val();`

Um exemplo 200 ml pegar apenas o valor 200.

mas o `console.log(tamanho)` retorna `200 ml` e preciso apenas do valor, se não fica impossível fazer cálculos.

qual expressão regular devo usar para capturar apenas os numeros do input?
onde devo colocar essa expressão regular para adicionar o valor a variavel `tamanho`?

Comment: `tamanho = parseInt( $("#tamanho").val() );` - nesse caso é bom que os numeros não tenham zero a esquerda, para que nenhuma implementação entenda como octal. Veja a sintaxe do @Sergio a seguir para especificar a base manualmente, e também a documentação da MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: `parseInt(nr, 10)`

Comment: @bacco `tamanho = parseInt( $("#tamanho").val() );` resolveu o problema agora estou recebe os 200 apenas e precisa fazer uma divisão com ele com um numero real, mas estou recebendo NAN de resposta

Comment: Aí é por causa do R$ prefixando o valor. Você até pode ficar contornando essas coisas, perguntando e o pessoal respondendo, mas sempre vai ser uma espécie de gambiarra. Provavelmente o ideal seria você aproveitar que está desenvolvendo, e separar o que é moeda, o que é valor e o que é unidade, não só por facilitar a sua vida, mas principalmente por ser o mais correto na grande maioria das situações. R$ é uma string fixa, pode ir fora do campo. Então eu sugeriria já arrumar isso antes de prosseguir (claro, a aplicação é sua, você deve fazer como achar melhor, só dei a dica enquanto é tempo).

Comment: Entao mas quando eu dou um console log no valor ele só retorna o numero, e não o R$... por exemplo o usuario coloca R$ 3,50, 200 ml, eu recebo 3,50 e 200 no console, achei que a divisão seria efetuada com esses valores...

Comment: o problema na verdade era a virgula no lugar do ponto no numero real.... valeu pela ajuda amigao! sempre bom aprender

Comment: é, a virgula realmente precisa ser tratada, mas é basicamente o que o sérgio já tratou com `.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');`, removendo os pontos todos, e trocando a virgula por um ponto. o problema neste caso é se o usuário usar um ponto no lugar da vírgula, mas entendendo a lógica você adapta mais fácil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se essa string tem valores primeiro e letras/unidades depois podes usar o [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) que ignora o que vem depois dos numeros e dá como retorno um numero, ie de *tipo*: `number`.

```
var tamanho = parseInt($("#tamanho").val(), 10);
```

Se precisares de valores com parte decimal, aí fica um pouco mais específico e podes fazer assim:

```
var string = $("#tamanho").val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
var tamanho = parseFloat(string.match(/[\d\,\.]+/)[0]);
```

O [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) transforma uma string em numero com parte decimal, mas é mais limitado que o `parseInt`, tens de ter a string só com dígitos e usando o ponto para indicar a parte decimal e não a virgula.

Exemplos:

```js
var tamanhoSimples = '200 ml';
console.log(parseInt(tamanhoSimples, 10));

var tamanhoComParteDecimal = '5.200.544,46 ml';
var stringLimpa = tamanhoComParteDecimal.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
console.log(parseFloat(stringLimpa.match(/[\d\,\.]+/)[0]));
```